# Is is possible to use Azure AD as a SAML compliant Identity Provider?

Tags: azure, active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, azure-active-directory

And if this is possible how would one set this is up (minimal installation). I have seen there is ACS but that doesn't support the SAML protocol. I also know I can use AD FS to bridge this but I want this to be a simple as possible - out of the box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195591.aspx  Azure AD provides a SAML endpoint for your directory automatically.

Comment: @RickRainey thx. So it should be possible but can't find good documentation about how to use and configure it.

Comment: That's the best documentation I know of and I don't recall seeing a SAML-P sample in the Azure AD samples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. The key is some "missing" documentation:

*Set-MsolDomainAuthentication   ,,, -PreferredAuthenticationProtocol SAMLP*

Refer: [SAML : Federating with Azure Active Directory using SAML](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/06/saml-federating-with-azure-active.html).